# Error using pip with requirements.txt

Tags: python, python3, pip

I have never used `requirements.txt` before, and just came across it following a tutorial. My file looks like this:

```
pip install kivy
pip install kivy-deps.angle
pip install kivy-deps.glew
pip install kivy-deps.gstreamer
pip install kivy-deps.sdl2
```

Yet when I run `pip install-r requirements.txt`, I get the error:

```
ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'pip install kivy' (from line 1 of requirements.txt)
```

Kivy installs fine if I do a plain `pip install kivy`. What is wrong with this scenario?

Comment: As alluded to below, simply remove `pip install` before each package name (i.e. make a plain list of just package names). And for future reference, while [requirements files technically do not need to contain version specifiers](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#example-requirements-file), including them is often not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a valid `requirements.txt` file, it's a list of shell commands. You could run it with a shell:

```
bash requirements.txt
```

Renaming it would be a good idea to avoid confusion.

A valid `requirements.txt` file is usually produced by running `pip freeze` in an environment with dependencies already installed and redirecting its output to a file:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

It can also be crafted manually. It would look somewhat like this:

```
kivy==1.11.1
kivy-deps.angle==0.2.0
kivy-deps.glew==0.2.0
kivy-deps.gstreamer==0.2.0
kivy-deps.sdl2==0.2.0
```

As you can see, it doesn't specify just package names, but also their versions. This way you're always installing known good versions of dependencies.